# Counter Display Design

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, touch

I am new to Python and took on a small project for the firehouse.
I am looking to make a "Calls YTD" Sign.
The initial thought was a raspberry Pi connected to the a touch screen.
After some playing around and learning how to use python a little I realized one very important fact... I am way over my head.

Looking for some direction.

In order for this to display on the touch screen I will need to build it into a GUI.  Should I stop right there and instead get a 12x12 LED and keep it more simple?

Otherwise the goal would be to display the current call number "61" for example, with an up and down arrow to simply advance or retract a number .

Adding the ability to display last years call volume would be cool but not necessary.

What I am looking for ultimately, is some direction if python and raspberry pi is the way to go or should I head in another direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a gui you could always take a look into Tkinter.
You could test the gui without having the actual raspberry pi.
Switching to leds would require an LED matrix, which is more demanding in terms of electrical engineering. Raspberry pi would be my recommendation.